# Exception using JRebel in Eclipse Juno

Tags: spring, jboss, jrebel

I`m trying to start a web application using JBoss 4.2.3, Spring with JRebel enabled.

I`m getting the following exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.reparse(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition;
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
>     br.com.mint.common.filter.ClientAbortConnectionFilter.doFilter(ClientAbortConnectionFilter.java:25)
>     br.com.mint.common.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.reparse(Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition;
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.ComponentScanner.doScan(ComponentScanner.java:67)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.ComponentScanner.scan(ComponentScanner.java:56)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.doRescan(AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.java:177)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.doRescan(AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.java:157)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.rescan(AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.java:133)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.annotations.AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.checkRescan(AnnotationBeanDefinitionManager.java:115)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.SpringBeanReloader.reloadBeanDefinitionsInternal(SpringBeanReloader.java:453)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.SpringBeanReloader.reloadBeanDefinitions(SpringBeanReloader.java:434)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.SpringBeanReloader.doCheckAndReloadBeanDefinitions(SpringBeanReloader.java:408)
>     org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.SpringBeanReloader.checkAndReloadBeanDefinitions(SpringBeanReloader.java:393)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.containsBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.containsBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.containsBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1096)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:51)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:86)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
>     org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:229)
>     org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:152)
>     org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:75)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
>     javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>     br.com.mint.common.filter.ClientAbortConnectionFilter.doFilter(ClientAbortConnectionFilter.java:25)
>     br.com.mint.common.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
>     org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you enable spring support on your jrebel?

Comment: I`m trying with this vm argument: -Drebel.spring_data_plugin=true.

Comment: Until now, nothing worked so far.

Comment: When you start server with jrebel  you should have this lines [2012-12-11 15:56:01] JRebel: Directory 'C:\project\target\classes' will be monitored for changes.
[2012-12-11 15:56:01] JRebel: Directory 'C:\project\src\main\webapp' will be monitored for changes. Are they correct?

Comment: and also this lines JRebel-Spring: Monitoring Spring bean definitions in 'C:\project\target\classes\spring\servlet-context.xml'.
[2012-12-11 15:56:03] JRebel-Spring: Monitoring Spring bean definitions in 'C:\project\target\classes\spring\services.xml'.
[2012-12-11 15:56:03] JRebel-Spring: Monitoring Spring bean definitions in 'C:\project\target\classes\spring\jackson.xml'. Or something like this.

Comment: Also do you install plugin for eclipse to use Jrebel ?

Answer (score 0):

After working a long time on this, I thought it was a good idea to move back to Eclipse Indigo. After installing all plugins and solved all problems related to classpath, it is working fine.

Comment: actually, the initial problem doesn't seem to be related to Eclipse version since the exception comes from JRebel Spring integration code. You could rather send a log file to JRebel support, just in case if it is a real bug.